# Installed ColdFusion 9 Developer Edition. How do I view CF pages in my browser?

Tags: coldfusion

I have just installed ColdFusion 9 Developer Edition on my Windows Vista machine for development purposes. Unfortunately I have yet to locate any documentation or tutorials as to where I place my files and how to view them in a browser. A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

FYI, I also have WAMP installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the install, it would've asked you if you wanted to use the "Built-in Web server (development use-only)" or if you wanted to "configure web server connector for ColdFusion": if you want to use your existing Apache (as part of WAMP), you need to configure a web server connector and specify the appropriate paths (where Apache is installed, where the webroot is, etc.).

**EDIT**

If you chose the built-in web server option, you should be able to go to: http://127.0.0.1:8500 and pull up the "welcome" page; more info is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd8.html).  Also your webroot would've been asked/specified during the install, but you can change it through the administrator I believe or the mappings file (it's been a while since I've used CF).

Comment: So my best bet is to uninstall and re-install configuring CF to work with my existing Apache installation?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: I was halfway through reinstalling when you made your edit. I can't get the CF Admin working but it does seem to be handling CF files in my www WAMP directory. I'll play around a bit and see if I can get it right but this was the point in the right direction I was looking for.

Comment: You should be able to go to http://127.0.0.1/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm